# Using Typescript how do I useRef to access react-select methods?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-select, react-typescript

I am learning React & Typescript and am attempting to create a "search filter" composed of 3 react-select dropdowns.

I populate 1st dropdown with vehicle makes, then 2nd with ranges for the selected vehicle make and 3rd with vehicle models using the selected id from vehicle range select object.

All is working but I need to clear down selected values of select objects upon changes or previous values still show that are not applicable for new selections.

I have tried to implement useRef, that I have read about online, and it is working so values clear when needed but method calls are reporting error in IDE, I need to understand how I can reference the correct "type" in setting up my useRef so the methods are known in code.

Below is one of my react components with a react-select element and my code to call methods "hasValue" & "clearValue" which are showing errors *"Property 'clearValue' does not exist on type 'RefObject'."*:

```
"use client"
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react"
import { SearchFilterAPI } from "../../api/searchFilter"
import Select from 'react-select'
import { CustomFilterProps } from '@/types';

const VehicleModels = ({ id, handleSelect }: CustomFilterProps) => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

    let selectRef = useRef<Select>(null);
    const clearValue = () => {
        ***if (selectRef.hasValue()) {
            selectRef.clearValue();***
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            // Fetch data
            if (typeof id !== "undefined" && id > 0) {
                clearValue();
                setOptions([]);
                let data = await SearchFilterAPI.getModelsForRangeId(id);
                let results = [];
                // Store results in the results array
                data.forEach((item) => {
                    results.push({
                        value: item.id,
                        label: item.name
                    });
                });
                // Update the options state
                setOptions([...results])
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }, [id]);

    return (
        <div>
            Vehicle Model
            <Select 
                ref={ref => {
                    selectRef = ref;
                }} 
                placeholder="Select vehicle model..." 
                options={options} 
                onChange={handleSelect}></Select>
        </div>
    );
}
export default VehicleModels;
```

Really need help understanding why these methods are not available at compile time.

Thanks in advance for any advice or example code with pointers on how works.

Answer (score 0):

Similar case with react-select where we needed to reset select option to zero after making selection. (actually we are using chakra-react-select but as it is only a wrapper to react-select the following works for both)

First instantiate the select ref.

```
const selectRef = useRef<SelectInstance<ISelectOption | null>>(null)
```

SelectInstance is imported from react-select. ISelectOption is the type of the options eg {label:'',value:0}. Then add select ref to point to the select element.

```
<Select ref={selectRef} ... />
```

Then we can use ref in select event handler such as:

```
onChange={(e) => {
    selectRef.current?.focus()
}}
```

More discussion about ref types can be found here: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/discussions/4669#discussioncomment-1994888.

Hope this gives more insight how to utilize refs.